# Static pointer + public constructor

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, static

[using C++] I know the pattern of Singleton, where constructor is being `private` and there is a static pointer to the `class`, returned from some `static GetInstance()` function. But when is the class with public constructor needed, such as this:

```
//hpp file
class MyClass{
    static MyClass * myptr;
public:
    static const MyClass * GetInstance() { return myptr; }

    MyClass() { myptr = this };
    ~MyClass() {}
    ...
}

//cpp file
MyClass * MyClass::myptr = nullptr;
```

What is happening each time we create new object using the constructor? `myptr` is overwritten? What are possible use cases for this pattern?

Comment: The simple answer is that this sort of code is never needed. Where does it come from? What does its author suggest is the benefit?

Comment: in addition, how you will delete the overwritten instances of `myptr` related to this instruction `MyClass() { myptr = this };` ?

Comment: it is from the codebase I am working with

Comment: @user2376997 If possible you should talk to the author of the code. But to me it just looks like bad code.

Comment: `static MyClass * myptr;` is a declaration. How is `myptr` defined?

Comment: @walnut, just added definition. it is originally in `.cpp` file

Comment: As an aside - that placing of the definition won't actually work. It has to go in a .cpp file.

Comment: This changes the pointer each time the constructor is called. I don't see the singletone here. Also you don't need static keyword on last line.

Comment: @JasperKent It is in `.cpp`, OP wrote that in comment.

Comment: And the `static` keyword should not be on the definition.

Comment: @JasperKent, removed it, thanks

Comment: `GetInstance` should be renamed `GetLastInstance`, but `~MyClass() {}` so creates dangling pointer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is happening each time we create new object using the constructor? `myptr` is overwritten?

Yes.

> What are possible use cases for this pattern?

One I can think of is a very simplified singleton usage - if you are *100% sure* there will be only one object created (e.g. you create one instance in `main()` and it lives through the whole program), then it's quite safe. But only in such a case - you must be very disciplined to keep it valid.

Answer (score 4):

Horrible things could go wrong with this. For example:

```
void func()
{
    MyClass obj; // Memory allocated on stack here and put into static pointer
} // Stack memory deallocated here

int main()
{
    func();

    const MyClass* ptr = MyClass::GetInstance(); // Dangling pointer
}
```

Just don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is interesting. It's not regular singleton, but similar in some ways.

Think about this scene:

1. Several threads maintain `MyClass::myptr`, and each thread could overwrite it.
2. Several threads use `MyClass::myptr` as regular singleton(actually it's not).